# Двойная замена url в htacces?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Добрый день! Суть вопроса такова.
Есть 2 файла:

- index.html
- index-cat=2.html

На основном индексе, ссылка ведет на

> index?cat=2

, т.е. в строке ссылка имеет вид

> mysite.com/index?cat=2.

Мне необходимо сделать, чтобы при обращении к ссылке вида index?cat=2, информация бралась из index-cat=2.html
Но чтобы в самой браузерной строке ссылка была вида - index?cat=2

Из всего, что испробовал получилось только перенапривить на html файл.

Буду очень признателен за помощь.